# iOS app Facebook integration - fallback for iOS 5.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ios6

I'm using the native Facebook integration for my iOS app and it's working great, but my target is iOS 5.0 and above. The Facebook API is available only in iOS 6.0+, so my question is how can I "remove" the facebook integration for older iOS versions? Right now when I build I'm getting this:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
  Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/96919EDB-C9E9-4862-ABA2-67ABAFAFB9BE/Tlipo.app/Tlipo
  Reason: image not found`

I want to keep the FB integration only for iOS 6+ users, so I just want to remove it from iOS 5 devices. How do I remove the libraries so that my app doesn't crash in iOS 5?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click on Xcode project.
2. Goto Build Phases
3. Expand "Link Binary With Libraries"
4. For (1)Social.framework(2)Account.framework(3)AdSupport.framework
   Select **Optional** (At the far right hand side, by default they will have **Required** as selected)

*Following the above mentioned steps, You are telling your App that only load those framworks if available (means for iOS 6.0 and upwards)*

It should look like this after following the steps mentioned:

[image]

Most probably your problem will be solved.

Let me know, whether it worked or not!

Comment: Worked perfectly. I didn't know that the SDK would work with iOS 5. I thought it's iOS 6+, but it seems like only the native authentication and dialogs are 6+.. anyway :) It's fine!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the SDK from Facebook instead of the one from Apple. The officla SDK from Facebook supports iOS 5.0 as well, and it is pretty easy to use.
Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/